# How to read arguments value from property file in custom validator in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created custom validator annotation for firstname as follows:

```
public class ProfileBean {

    @FirstNameValidator(minLength = 2L, maxLength = 10L, pattern = "firstname_pattern}",channelId="abcd")
    private String firstName;
}
```

`ProfileBean` is my POJO and in custom annotation I want to read `minLength`, `maxLength` and pattern value from properties file. How can I do this?

I have one more problem I have to support different channels. For all these channels beans will be different but annotations for given fields are same as follows:
Channel1:
 public class ProfileBean {

```
    @FirstNameValidator(minLength = 5L, maxLength = 100L, pattern = "[A-Za-z]{5,100}",channelId="abcd")
    private String firstName;
}
```

Channel2:
 public class RegisterBean {

```
    @FirstNameValidator(minLength = 2L, maxLength = 10L, pattern = "[A-Za-z]{2,10}}",channelId="xyz")
    private String foreName;
}
```

In this case validation implementation is same, but it might be a case that argument value can be different for different channels. In this case in implementation how can we load different properties based on channels. 
In my case I have defined message bean in xml and and by using instance of that bean I have to read property value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do it in your `ProfileBean` as everything passed into Annotation value must be Constant Expressions. What you can do is

```
public @interface FirstNameValidator {

    public String minLengthProp() default "min.length";

    public String maxLengthProp() default "max.length";

    public String patternProp() default "min.length";

    ...

}
```

And in your Custom Validator's `initialize` method implementation

```
private Properties properties ... // Load properties

private ThreadLocal<Integer> maxLength = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();
private ThreadLocal<Integer> minLength = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();
private ThreadLocal<String> pattern = new ThreadLocal<String>();

@Override
public void initialize(FirstNameValidator firstNameValidator) {
    if(firstNameValidator.minLength() == null) {
        minLength.set(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty(firstNameValidator.minLengthProp())));

    }

    ...
}
```

And in your `isValid` method

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(User user,
        ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    minLength.get() 

    ...

}
```

And Annotate as following in your `ProfileBean`

```
@FirstNameValidator(minLengthProp = "name.minLength", maxLengthProp = "name.maxLength", patternProp = "name.pattern")
```